# set image size with respect to the screen resolution

Tags: css, image, size, resolution

I am trying to build a website for myself.. I want to use an image as the header... I have made sure that my background will scale itself for any screen resolution... How do i make sure the image(header) will also scale it self according to the screen resolution...

for example: my image is 350px int width and 130px in height.. i want this to be the size when screen resolution is 1280X768.. and should change proportionally based on screen size..

Please tell me how to do this preferably using CSS.. i am also fine with js or jquery

Thanks in advance
Raj

Answer (score 5):

If you only specify the width in css, the height will scale automatically. You can easily specify the with of the image **relative to its parent**.

In your example you would have to specify `width: 27%` (1280 / 350). Note that the parent will have to be 100% wide.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the screen size from the DOM using `screen.width` and `screen.height`. Then you can write some JS to load or replace with the desired image or adjust the `height`/`width` attributes on the image (which would scale it, but doesn't always look great).

Comment: How is it possible? I have the same problem, and I'm not going any where I had try everything and nothing can fit the image on the screen.. I got the resolution with JS, but how to put the value inside the css width and height properties?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good article on fluid grids by Ethan Marcotte, http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluidgrids/

You can apply these principals to your images using CSS, he does on his personal site. There even good apps to help you out.

this one has a read me -> web duck
http://inteldesigner.com/web-duck/about.php

this one has more features -> em calc
http://riddle.pl/emcalc/